# Modulo operator gives different results with leading zeroes

Tags: c++, modulo

Why does:

```
int test() {
    return 00101 % 10;
}
```

return `5`, while:

```
int test() {
    return 101 % 10;
}
```

returns `1`? I can't think of an explanation.

Answer (score 23):

Integer literals beginning with `0` like

```
00101
```

is actually an octal constant.

Comment: This is the most confusing convention ever, it's totally contradictory to the way humans look at numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to work around this? I'm receiving values and I don't know how many leading zeroes there will be.

Comment: @KosmasKatsoulotos How did you receive the values? You don't encounter this problem much other than dealing with literals.

Comment: If you `fscanf` or whatever, `%d` in the format string will ignore/strip/interpret as decimal the leading zeroes. (`%o` is octal).

Answer (score 5):

`00101` is octal value which is `65` in decimal so it returns `5`.

Answer (score 0):

00101 is in octal which is equal to 65 in decimal, so that is why the modulus operator will always give us 5.
You can do octal to decimal converstion on this link http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/octal-to-decimal.htm

Comment: You said "hex", but meant "octal", and anyway all the other answers before you got it right.

Comment: hex means it should start with 0x.

Comment: @AndyG Its now corrected and I was already going to correct it

Comment: @Rustam yes you are right hex starts with 0x